# Get object apiname based on recordid in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-object, describesobject, record

Is it possible to het the object apiname based on a recordId in a lwc without a call to apex?

Something like apex but then without going to backend:

```
Id recordId = '001g000001jmmCA';
System.debug('Object Name: '+ recordId.getsobjecttype());
```

I currently have a handleRowAction(event) which gets the record id from a lightning-datatable which dynamically gets fields and values as a replacement of related lists. I use this component several times on e.g. account record, so on handle handleRowAction(event) it would be easy to get the object by recordId so I can pass recordId and object to a lightning-record-form:

```
<lightning-record-form record-id={recId} object-api-name={sObj} mode="readonly"
                                layout-type="Full" columns="5" fields="Name">
```

I already solved this by an apex call to the backend but was wondering if this could be done easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record) and pass in the `recordId` parameter to get the [Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record.htm) response, which includes the `apiName` property. You still will need a call to the server, but you won't need any Apex.

Comment: I get the error "getRecord" is a wire adapter and can only be used via the wire decorator. So is there a way to call this from a handleRowAction(event)?

Comment: @Thomas That would have been helpful information in the question . I'd be happy to expand on this answer, just be more descriptive in your question.

Comment: Just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use @objectApiName